# Cannot use functions between files in python

Tags: python

I have a huge project split up into 3 files.  I normally have no problem using functions from one file in another file, but this time I am not able to do this.  Further, I don't quite understand why one of my lists that I pass between files is disappearing after it passes out of the function.

**File: settings.py**

```
list1 = []
```

**File: globals.py**

```
from settings import *
def foo(hey):
    global list1
    list1.append(hey)
```

**File: new_code.py**

```
from settings import *
from globals import *
def cool_function():
    global list1
    list1 = []
    hey = "you"
    foo(hey)
    print (list1)


cool_function()
```

The problem is that my code cannot call foo from `globals.py`. I get an indentation error at foo.  Even if that problem was solved, on the real project I'm working on list1 gets appended to in the `settings.py` file, but then it returns to empty after i return to the cool_function.

#

Update: even by removing `list1 = []` in the `new_code.py` file the code still is not able to call the function foo from `settings.py`.  Here are the files if you want to take a look:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZiTwl-DOPfZCrrrA1kBcBHh8c9AInFLI/view?usp=sharing > files

#

Update:  I changed the `globals.py` file to

from settings import *
def foo(hey):
   list1.append(hey)

And the `new_code.py` files to

```
from settings import *
from globals import *
global list1
def cool_function():

    list1 = []
    hey = "you"
    foo(hey)
    print (list1)


cool_function()
```

And that solved the problem but I don't understand why.

Comment: Using import * is considered bad practice, use import func1,func2,func3

Answer (score 1):

**2 bad ideas:**

1. use `globals` as a module name, `globals` is a built-in function's name.
2. use `global` statement.

If you want to keep a global list object, a good practise is to wrap it to an object. Let it become a ref-type variable.

**a better practise:**

in settings.py:

```py
class Settings(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

settings = Settings()
```

in your new_code.py:

```py
from settings import settings

def cool_function():
    settings.items.append('something')
    return settings.items

print(cool_function())
```

Comment: Thanks but can you provide a solution without using classes?  I do not like classes and do not use them.  To my mind, they just make things more complicated.

Comment: @fredrussell not have to use a class to do this. Actully your code would be just fine if you remove the line `list1 = []` in new_code.py.

Answer (score 0):

If you get an indentation error you should use  your text editor's "render whitespace" feature to find the indentation problem

Comment: It's not an indentation error.  The code cannot call the function from the other file and for that reasons thinks it's an indentation error even though it's not.

Answer (score 0):

In `new_code.py` move `globals list1` from `cool_funtion` to above `cool-function`